# browse my answers with a specific keyword filter is not working

Tags: discussion, support

I am unable to go through my own answers with a specific filter.

From one of the questions, I got filter command as follows

**populate is:answer [javascript] user:me**

I tried the command as follows

**populate is:answer [java] user:me**

I got the out put only for one question. Searched the same command with hadoop etc but did not work as expected.

Please suggest a solution to view my own answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works as designed.

If I search for [`user:4999394 is:answer [hadoop] hdfs`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4999394+is%3Aanswer+%5Bhadoop%5D+hdfs) I find your answers that contain the word *hdfs*.

Similar [`patient is:answer [java] user:4999394`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=patient+is%3Aanswer+%5Bjava%5D+user%3A4999394) finds one answer with the word *patient*.

You don't find an answer with the word *populate*  if you don't write an answer with that word in it.

If I use SEDE to find your answers with this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400277):

```
select id as [Post Link]
from posts
where posttypeid = 2 --Answer
and owneruserid = 4999394 -- ravindra
and body like '%populate%'
```

You only have 1 answer with that word, the one you found, and that question is only tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Searching for *populate* in the [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop) tag will render no results, as expected.

You might check your deleted recent answers on your profile in case one of your answers got deleted that had those words in it.

Comment: I thought that populate is part of query. It is working fine for me now after removing that string.